# How to use the media segementer in the mac?

Tags: iphone, mediastreamsegmenter

I have a url of a video.I want to segment it using mediastreamsegmenter  in the mac.how can i do that.Any step by step tutorials will be more helpful.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

On your mac, you can do man {mediatool} (e.g. man mediafilesegmenter) and those examples are pretty good, otherwise I'd start with this reference from Apple

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2224/_index.html

*note - make sure you use the mediastreamvalidator before submitting apps to Apple to make sure you have the correct min. values for video (base 64k and no video just audio).